# Is it possible to add a page onto a page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, overlay

I have a page and on that page is a button. When the button is clicked, another page (has to be from a different xaml file) is placed on top of the previous page. The user should be able to see the previous page but not be able to access it...kind of like an overlay. The user can only interact with the new page. Is this possible to do in WPF? I've been searching for this without much success. Thanks!

Comment: You might find a child window useful for that: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-child-window/

Comment: Or other options like [show dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx). Either way I'm curious what searches didn't bring up anything, it's a pretty common task to do modal style child windows.

Comment: @ChrisW. I guess I was searching for the wrong terms. Thank you for suggesting show dialog, I will check it out.